# How would I restrict visitors from changing the size of text on my web page?

Tags: user-interface

How would I restrict visitors from changing the size of text on my web page (like by means of Strl + +/- in Firefox)?

Comment: please don't do that!

Comment: Why do people try do cripple user experience all the time? Don't do that for fear of http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001137.html

Comment: I agree that the OP's plan is a very bad idea, but it's a very valid and reasonably phrased programming question and does not deserve negative vote.

Comment: I don't think he asked for a moral judgment of his question. I think he asked for a solution. I don't think somebody should change the browser zoom behavior either, but this is not a place to judge his question but to provide an answer or keep quiet. my 2ct.

Comment: Exactly, the question doesn't deserve a down vote

Comment: I agree with balpha and Alex. Even though totally unethical and other things I dare not say, the question is valid and shouldn't be downvoted. Downvotes are not for agreement/disagreement. Just read the tooltips: "This question is unclear or not useful".

Comment: @balpha: while I didn't downvote the question myself, I can totally understand those who did. Gjr must provider much more context and reason for what he's asking before we can help him, both because of the ignorance of the workings of HTML as well as the disregard for the users. Thus the question is neither helpful through exploring an interesting programming niche nor helpful by providing a valid case where zooming should be avoided.

Comment: @Martinho, well the question is **not*** useful. and most certainly doesn't deserve upvotes either.

Comment: @David Schmitt: The question is: "How do I...?" And in the end, if the answer is not only "You can't", but also "You can't, because..." and "It's a good thing that you can't, because...", how much more helpful could the whole thing be for the next person looking for the answer to the same question?

Answer (score 17):

You can't, and most certainly you shouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure there are vile techniques that you could use to achieve this - but why would you?

Not everyone has good eyesight - without glasses, my eyesight is 3:56, but I'm lucky enough to have corrective lenses that bring me close to 20:20. Not everyone is so lucky - **many users need to change font sizes to see your site at all**.

Comment: @phoenix, ha ha, because they are all afraid of... something =)

Comment: From my point of view there's nothing in this answer that deserves a down vote.

Answer (score 5):

There's no way -- HTML defines content first, so basing your layout on relying on this is a bad idea. There might be people with a high screen resolution who need to zoom. There might be people using a text-only browser or screen reader where the whole concept is different, thus you can't rely on anything.

There might even be people who don't have Arial (e.g.), so the text might render differently from how you saw it even with the same zoom settings. And I'm totally setting aside the different text layout engines in the different browsers.

If you need the degree of control that I interpret into your question: Use Flash, Silverlight, or even just graphics to present your content. I guess I don't have to tell you the obvious disadvantages of this approach.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid interfering with such user actions.

Answer (score 2):

One way that might get you this behaviour is to use images instead of text. Make a small image for each letter and write some code that converts a string into a list of those images.

This will not prevent users from zooming in to the page, but it will maintain your layout.

Note: I do agree with all other responses in that this is very bad practice and is probably evil as well. But, since SO is about answering questions and not ethics...

Comment: Yes, but not 'only' the images on the page. If you zoom in, layout is retained.

Answer (score 1):

This is really something you shouldn't do. Think about people with eyes trouble that needs to have large font.

If your website look ugly after you increased text size, it means your css is wrong/uncomplete.

Plus you can't prevent this.

Comment: That's it! Every website is gonna look ugly when you increased text size a fat lot!!! =) I'm concerned about it.

Comment: @Gjr, I agree that all (well, most) websites look ugly if you increase text size a lot, but users don't do that unless they need to in order to read the text. And those users just want to be able to read the text, and doesn't really care about all the nifty details in your design (they can't see it properly anyway).

Comment: Well, you can be concerned, but there's nothing you can do. Lot of people with eye problem use custom CSS, which can be parametred withing browser options, and not the cute and made-with-love CSS webmasters designed.

Comment: (And by the way, why was I downvoted ? I don't think I wron, am I ?)

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the look of your site when users use the zoom option, you should not eliminate that possibility. You should try to work with it, not forbid it.

The generally accepted guideline is that your site should work with:

1. The default font size
2. One size above the default
3. One size below the default

Answer (score 1):

OK, as everybody else here have said, I don't recomment you restricting this.

That said, there are different methods in the web browsers that does the resising.
IE is the only browser I know that allows you to lock the font size.

## IE:

### Text Size

Increases/Decreases texts only
This is actually suppressed if you specify a fixed font size in CSS

#### Example:

```
font-size: 14px;
```

### Zoom (new feature in IE7)

Increases/decreases the entire page, including all graphics and design features. This actually fits the content to the window as it would appear in 100%, and changes the size of that look (>100% causes scrollbars to appear). This cannot be influenced by anything you do in the web design.

---

## Firefox:

You can set it to zoom only text, or zoom everything.
Even when setting to zoom only text, you can not override it using the CSS style as in IE.
When zooming everything, Firefox still tries to fit the page within the window.

---

## Opera:

Does not have option to change only text size. Zoom everything. Like firefox, it tries to fit the page within the window.

Answer (score 0):

What will you do about people accessing the site via a text-only browser? They could be choosing to see your text in any typeface and size they like! MS Comic Sans 72 point!! The horror!!!